# How to do grouping by in JS?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an API which returns a JSON object like this:

```
plans: [{
    0 : {plan: "gold", amount: 5000},
    1: {plan: "silver", amount: 2000},
    3: {plan: "silver", amount: 1000},
    4: {plan: "gold", amount: -4000}
}]
```

I want to group the result by `plan`. So here is **the expected result**:

```
groupedPlans: [{
    "gold" : {amount: 1000},
    "silver" : {amount: 3000}
}]
```

Is it possible to do such a thing using JS? I know in other languages like SQL you can do that simply by using `GROUP BY plan`. But not sure how can I do that in JS.

Comment: JS doesn't have a standard "group by" like in SQL. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111048/javascript-how-to-groupby, and using reduce may be a good start

Comment: @ChrisG yes right

Comment: Do you really have an array of single object with 0..4 as keys?

Comment: @JanPfeifer yeah here is the real output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d8jJ.png

Comment: See [Converting JavaScript object with numeric keys into array](/q/20881213/4642212) and [Sum JavaScript object propertyA values with the same object propertyB in an array of objects](/q/19233283/4642212). Get familiar with [how to access and process objects, arrays, or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212), and use the static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: @MartinAJ there's no object with 0..4 as keys in the screenshot. `plans` is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a flat array and group by `plan`.

```js
const
    plans = [{ 0: { plan: "gold", amount: 5000 }, 1: { plan: "silver", amount: 2000 }, 3: { plan: "silver", amount: 1000 }, 4: { plan: "gold", amount: -4000 } }],
    result = plans
        .flatMap(Object.values)
        .reduce((r, { plan, amount }) => {
            (r[plan] ??= { amount: 0 }).amount += amount;
            return r;
        }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, working as expected. Just the data  I provided was a simplified of the real data, could you please tell me how can I add `user_id` to the result under `amount` too? https://jsfiddle.net/npgem0qt/

Comment: just destructure this property and add it to the default object, where `amount` is.